# sql #1005 - Can't create table (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql

I have

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `Companies` (
`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`name` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `id` )
) ENGINE = INNODB
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `Users` (
`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`name` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `id` )
) ENGINE = INNODB
```

I am trying to create table like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `UserCompanies` (
`role` INTEGER, 
`CompanyId` int(11) , 
`UserId` int(11) , 
`createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
`updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
UNIQUE `UserCompanies_UserId_CompanyId_unique` (`CompanyId`, `UserId`), 
PRIMARY KEY (`CompanyId`, `UserId`), 
FOREIGN KEY (`CompanyId`) REFERENCES `Companies` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `Users` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

`#1005 - Can't create table 'test.UserCompanies' (errno: 150)`

`id` in `Companies` and `Users` is

```
`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

and I am sure, that this column exists in those tables.

Comment: `show engine innodb status`, buried about 1/2 way down the output is a "last foreign key error" status section, it'll have details about what caused the problem.

Comment: I can see at least six matching questions immediately to the right.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit. I checked all of them, but I can not get what my problem is

Comment: Well all we can do here is repeat what people said on those existing questions, some of which provide step-by-step instructions on how to fix it... Can you be specific about what you have tried and what you got stuck on?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit. Ok, I will try to do so

Comment: @McAdam331 Yes, I have already created them.

Comment: As discussed in the other question, you cannot use `ON DELETE SET NULL` in this context.

Comment: @McAdam331 Thank you so much! I did not noticed that the second one is `ON DELETE SET NULL`